# Objects have same Transform but actually don't?

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

Can someone explain to me why these two objects have the same transform but the origins are clearly offset and local orientation is different too?
thx ._.
[image: Object1]

[image: Object2]

Comment: could you please share your 2 objects? https://pasteall.org/blend/